# Writing a regular expression to validate a telephone number

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

i want to validate a telephone number field as **can be null** and **if any entered then it should be 10 digits**. Does anyone know how I can write the regular expression for such? 
I'm using the @Pattern annotation to validate the telephone number.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean validate(String number) {
    return number == null || Pattern.compile("^\\d{10}$").find());
}
```

Comment: Cant we check the can null in a regular expression using an or operator cos im using the @Pattern annotation to validate the telephone number

Comment: From the javadoc (http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) : The annotated String must match the following regular expression. The regular expression follows the Java regular expression conventions see Pattern. Accepts String. **null elements are considered valid.**

Answer (score 0):

```
if (text != null && !text.matches("\\d{10}")) {
    // not a valid number
}
```

But since you just tols that you wanted to use the `@Pattern` annotation to validate a field, then the reqex is sufficient, since, as [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) says:

> The annotated String must match the following regular expression. The
>   regular expression follows the Java regular expression conventions see
>   Pattern. Accepts String. **null elements are considered valid**.

(emphasis mine)

So, just use `@Pattern("\\d{10}")`.

Comment: I tried it adding the regular expression -@Pattern("\\d{10}") , but then it still doesn't allows null, only checks for 10digits

Comment: Is your string null (s == null), or empty (s.length() == 0), or blank (s.trim().length() == 0)? Those are not the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
[0-9]{10}
```

If you have any more specific rules, please add them :)